# Getting negative pulse on Q2 mosfet at gate to source pin

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, buck-boost, bootstrap

**BOOST CIRCUIT:**

Working on DC-DC boost converter circuit as given bellow.

Getting negative pulse of -25.6V on Q2 mosfet at gate to source pin. This is much higher then then its maximum operating voltage. Due to this negative voltage my MOSFET gets burnt. I am using 1uF of bootstrap capacitor to turn on Q2 MOSFET. Please share if there is any solution to avoid this issue and how to compress this negative voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdQyoM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Use a bigger value R2 resistor and put a zener protection between gate and source.

Comment: @Andy aka, i have tested with 12v zener between gate to source 
 with 100ohm gate resistance. through this negative peak has removed but now gate resistance is heating much.

Comment: Try 1 kohm instead. But it may eat into your rise and fall times. What switching frequency? Ah 30 kHz. yes 1 kohm will be OK

Comment: mosfet get burn imminently

Comment: Then you need to redesign your gate driver so that it doesn't exceed the gate-source voltage.

Comment: did you found any issue in this gate drive circuit,

Comment: Apart from the unknown connection of the bootstrap capacitor there is no other issue apart from it producing an excessive gate-source voltage (as you have said). So, that circuit won't be correct and you need to redesign it.

Comment: gate driver circuit is same for both Q1 & Q2 gate, and providing two synchronous pulse so at a time Q1 mosfet will ON and Q2 will be OFF.

Comment: And this needs to change. Are we going round in circles here?

Comment: Andy can you help me redesign circuit.

I am open for any change suggested here

Comment: I don't mind checking over a design but I'm not going to design one from scratch. You need to do this and using a simulator is probably a good idea.

Comment: @Andyaka, as you already aware my problem of negative pulse at gate to source pin of Q2 mosfet is resolved by adding back to back zener connected, now my zener is getting heating at 73degree

Comment: 73 degrees celcius isn't a showstopper.

Comment: as you suggested i am going to redesign my gate drive circuit with NCP5109A ic